# Is it a best practice in Java to declare variables before give them as parameters

Tags: java, variables, final

Assuming this code :

```
public static Dataset<Row> getData(SparkSession sparkSession,
                                             StructType schema, String delimiter, String pathToData) {

    final Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession
            .read()
            .option("delimiter", "\\t")
            .csv(pathToData);

    StructType nSchema= newSchema(schema, schema.size(), dataset.columns().length);
 ...
}
```

Is it a best practice to declare variables and make them final before giving them to newSchema method, like this ?

```
public static Dataset<Row> getData(SparkSession sparkSession,
                                             StructType schema, String delimiter, String pathToData) {

    final Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession
            .read()
            .option("delimiter", "\\t")
            .csv(pathToData);

    final int dataSize = dataset.columns().length;
    final int schemaSize = schema.size();

    StructType nSchema = newSchema(schema, schemaSize, dataSize);
 ...
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of taste.

Introducing local variables allows you to name concepts. Have simpler statements. Simplify inner loops. Potentially remove common code without introducing new functions.

On the other hand. Naming is hard. The code will be shorter if you bung it all on one line. It may be easier to factor out code if it is not dependent on too many local variables.

`final` for locals is probably over the top, unless the code is already a mess.

Comment: I heartily agree with the last sentence.  In fact, `final` has no effect.  As of Java 8, all local variables are [effectively final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4-500) if they are assigned a value only once.

Comment: Thanks for the details, very good to know

Answer (score 1):

It depends, let's say you have a call like func(list.get(0).getName.toString())

It would be much more readable to just assign that to a variable and plug it in. Some people might not like the extra lines of code but to me it is worth assigning to a variable.